# How do you insert data from text file into SQL Server table using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyodbc

```
import pyodbc
import csv
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server;'
                      'Server=SIS10647\MSSQLSERVER14;'
                      'Database=LeelaVenkatesh;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute('''

               CREATE TABLE employee
               (
               empid int,
               Name nvarchar(50)
               )

               ''')

with open('C:\PYTHON\Textfiles/1.txt') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO employee(empid,name)
                          VALUES(%s, %s)
                       """, row)
conn.commit()
cursor.close()
print("Done")
```

I am getting the following error

> cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO employee(empid,name) pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('The SQL contains 0 parameter markers, but 1
> parameters were supplied', 'HY000')

Text file data looks like

```
empid|Name
1|'Ram'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO employee(empid,name)
                  VALUES(?, ?)
                  """, row)
```

and if this doesn't work, assuming row is an array, try this:

```
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO employee(empid,name)
                  VALUES(?, ?)
                  """, row[0], row[1])
```

Comment: IndexError: list index out of range       this is the error iam getting

Comment: so what isthe structure of row? like is it an array, if so, is the length of the array fixed for all the rows?

Comment: rows are sperated by delimter   |

Comment: could you give an example? Value of row

Comment: Added in question please look into it

Comment: so it is a string? right? or an array with just one string element delimited by: `|`?

Comment: try this: `reader = csv.reader(f, delimter="|")` and use the second method from my answer. The problem is not an SQL error anymore but more of python formatting...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225347/discussion-between-chanukya-and-illusion).

Comment: delimter' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Answer (score 0):

```py
empid|Name
1|'Ram'
try this
empid,Name
1,Ram
with 
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO employee(empid,name)
                  VALUES(?, ?)
                  """, row[0], row[1])
```

Comment: Also the file must have only values without headers, seperated by comma